# IP address and Datagridview control

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I am using a datagridview to get the IP address from user. Is there any way so that I can restrict the user to enter only valid ip address in the datagrid view cell?

Its a desktop application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can implement a [validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykdxa0bc.aspx) that enforces the requirements you want.  Are you asking how to write such a validator?

Answer (score 0):

you can do .

in [gridcellvaliating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvalidating.aspx) event use some [ip address regular expression validation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html)